# Sequence contains no elements when mocking repository

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to mock the repository code below:

```
var simulatorInstance = bundleRepository
    .FindBy<CoreSimulatorInstance>(x => x.CoreSimulatorInstanceID == instanceID)
    .Single();
```

but I get an error that states the "Sequence contains no elements". I tried changing the `.Single` to `SingleOrDefault`, but that returns a `null`.

In my unit test I mocked my the repository using the following:

**This does not work**

```
this.mockedRepository.Setup(
    x => x.FindBy<CoreSimulatorInstance>(
        z => z.CoreSimulatorInstanceID == 2))
            .Returns(coreSimulatorInstancesList.AsQueryable());
```

**This work for now using the `Is.Any` because I only have one record**

```
this.mockedRepository.Setup(
    x => x.FindBy<CoreSimulatorInstance>(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<CoreSimulatorInstance, bool>>>()))
            .Returns(coreSimulatorInstancesList.AsQueryable());
```

I want to mock the code using the `.Single`.

Comment: What is `coreSimulatorInstancesList` and where is it instantiated? In your code or in your test? What type does your `FindBy` method return?

Comment: Is the instanceID correct in the test?

Comment: well, the obvious point is that either `bundleRepository` does not actually contain any single item where `CoreSimulatorInstanceID == instanceID`...or `bundleRepository` is itself empty...which seems unlikely given that you later state it contains a single record.

Comment: Your question is very unclear as to what you have and what you want to achieve.  Your code marked "This does not work" for example, we are unable to see why because we haven't got the code for "coreSimulatorInstancesList".  My guess would be that you don't have an item with "CoreSimulatorInstanceID" of "2".  But it's hard to tell as you haven't provided all the details.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using Moq to setup the repository's `FindBy` method so that business logic code hits the mocked method when you're running your test.

I think that the issue is that Moq is unable to match the parameter you provided during the mock setup with the parameter you provide during the execution of your business logic code, resulting in your mocked repository method not being executed and `coreSimulatorInstancesList` not being returned.

Since the parameter you provided to Moq during setup is an expression

```
z => z.CoreSimulatorInstanceID == 2
```

even when your business logic code executes with `instanceID` of 2

```
x => x.CoreSimulatorInstanceID == instanceID
```

resulting in an expression that is equivalent to the one you setup in the mock, they are still not matched because they are different expressions. These are two different expression objects. I don't think there's a way for Moq to know that they are equivalent and match your mocked method based on that.

I would go with `Is.Any` approach. If you want to be more thorough I think you would need to hand build a custom fake repository class in this case.